# AS-AD Model, what would fall in production/output lead to?

Tags: macroeconomics

Suppose there is some exogenous shock in the economy due to which the production of oil has fallen dramatically. Also, let's assume that oil forms a substantive part of the economy's production. What effects are we likely to see in the economy? What would happen to the IS-LM and AS/AD curve?

My understanding: A decrease in output will lead to a decrease in the price level (this will work through the labor market). But I'm confused about whether there will be a shift in the aggregate supply curve?

Comment: It would be helpful to tell us what you have thought of so far.

Comment: A decrease in output will lead to a decrease in the price level (this will work through the labor market). But I'm confused about whether there will be a shift in the aggregate supply curve?